# Wordpress is generating Undefined variable:post in function.php

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site was working fine. I did not change anything, but today morning it just showing an error about which i have no clue why its showing like this and how to solve is. The errors i am getting:

1. Notice: Undefined variable: post in /home/afch1ealth1/public_html/wp-content/themes/afc/functions.php on line 154.
2. Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_date in /home/afch1ealth1/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 4582.

And in function.php on line 154 i have used the below codes:

```
<?php 

    function excerpt($num) {

    $limit = $num+1;
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ", $excerpt)."<a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'class='".readmore."'> [Read More]</a>"; <-------- this is exact 154 line

    echo $excerpt;

    }
   ?>
```

Though i am getting this errors, but my wordpress is working perfectly.

I have attach a image here for your better understanding.

Comment: Notice message is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I think you are missing `global $post;` at the begin of your function.

Comment: @pbaldauf: Why would you need that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    function excerpt($num) {
    global $post;
    $limit = $num+1;
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ", $excerpt)."<a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'class='readmore'> [Read More]</a>"; <-------- this is exact 154 line

    echo $excerpt;

    }
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it solved my problem but now showing a new error that is :  Notice: Use of undefined constant readmore - assumed 'readmore' in /home/afch1ealth1/public_html/wp-content/themes/afc/functions.php on line 152 and my exact 152 no code is  $excerpt = implode(" ", $excerpt)."<a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'class='".readmore."'> [Read More]</a>";

Answer (score 0):

Notice: Undefined variable: post in /home/afch1ealth1/public_html/wp-content/themes/afc/functions.php on line 154.

In PHP **Notice:** is call you are small problem in your function

> This issue is solve while you are declare variable **$post = '';**

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_date in /home/afch1ealth1/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 4582.

This issue solve while you are **query.php on line 4582.**

> **isset ($variable)**

[wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress)